# BingMap Heatmap module blocks map events

Tags: bing-maps

I'm using Heatmap module and faced with following issue.

When I create polygon and attach events to polygon like click\mouseenter\mouseleave etc, events are not fired.

If I disable Heatmap module everything works fine, so need somehow to forward events through Heatmap layer.

Please advice.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this. I tried adding a click event to the map and it works fine.

Comment: Probably map events works, I don't use them. Try to attach events to polygon on the map and enable heat map. I use chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at this. It appears that the heatmap is rendered above the polygon, which intern is blocking the click events. To get around this, in the init function of the heatmap source code you will see a line of code like this:

```
_mapDiv.childNodes[2].childNodes[1].appendChild(container);
```

Change it to this:

```
_mapDiv.childNodes[2].childNodes[0].appendChild(container);
```

Comment: Now it works, but heat map layer is covered by polygons color. Looks strange https://gyazo.com/b327d3a8533d9725390bd04b31361896. If there is no way to fix it, I mark you answer as correct, because it explicitly answers my question, but if you know how to make it look and work as expected, please advice. Thanks!

Comment: That's to be expected. Click events in general can't pass through an element. If the heatmap is above the polygons, then you can't click the polygons. If heatmap is below the polygons, you can.